# Openlayers 3 XYZ ZoomLevel doesn't work and displays wrong tiles on zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to make a map using a bigger picture, I've resized it and cut it using powers of 2 ( I have resized it from 1024 to 8192 [ 8 zoom levels] ). I'm trying to use the basic template maptiler gives off.

By keeping the default `minZoom(0)` and `maxZoom(4)` it displays the entire image, but when zooming in, after 2 zooms it starts calling for the wrong tiles : As if the map would move to the left by 1 tile or something.

When changing the `maxZoom` to 7, it only displays 1/4 of the image: the top left corner.

I've tried setting the `extent` to 8192, to the full res or to some big numbers, also tried using all the params in the extent but nothing seems to work.

What should I do to make this work? I see that maptiler even uses non-square images well, but all only on 4 levels of zoom ...